# Oracle Enterprise Manager Favicon

Tags: favicon, oracle-enterprise-manager

Our Oracle Enterprise Manager Grid Control 10.2.0.5 website has no favicon.  I don't know if this is normal or not.  If it is not normal I'll contact support, but if it is normal I'd like to know if there is a way to add one.  I would guess if I knew where the root of the website was I could put a favicon.ico file there, but I'm not sure how to determine where the root of the site is in the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Enterprise Manager for Oracle Forms Application server doesn't have a favicon over at my installation either.
The location to root of the site is

```
$oracle_home\Apache\Apache\htdocs
```

In my case, its

```
e:\Applsinfra\Apache\Apache\htdocs
```

Comment: I put a favicon.ico in my ...\Apache\Apache\htdocs\ folder, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: I just put a favicon, and it was picked up. Try clearing the cache and   loading. Worked like that for one of my installations

Comment: I tried clearing the cache, but that didn't work.  Perhaps it is different due to the Oracle Forms Application.

Comment: Which version of FOrms are you using ? Which browser are you using ? Try using Mozilla Firefox + HttpFox addon - the addon informs what HTTP requests are being made, that should tell you if the favicon is being fetched or not (indicated in this screenshot: http://www.imgx.org/public/view/full/18280 )

Comment: It just started working.  I'm not sure why it didn't work before.  Thanks for your help and for the addon tip.  HttpFox looks useful.